# Comment-like environments and spacing

Tags: spacing, environments, comments

I often need to "turn off" environments. One way I do this is below in my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{nothing}{\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}
{\egroup}

\begin{document}
Hello, this is some text.
\begin{nothing}
  This is nothing.
\end{nothing}
More text.

Hello, this is some text.
More text.
\end{document}
```

However, as you can see, [image: space made by nothing environment]

Some space is added. How do I fix this?

Comment: `\ignorespaces` after `\egroup` perhaps. Though the comment package might be better

Comment: remember that `\stepcounter` ... works inside `savebox`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `\ignorespacesafterend`; but you can consider the `comment` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\newenvironment{nothing}
  {\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}
  {\egroup\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
Hello, this is some text.
\begin{nothing}
  This is nothing.
\end{nothing}
More text.

Hello, this is some text.
More text.

Hello, this is some text.
\begin{comment}
  This is nothing.
\end{comment}
More text.

Hello, this is some text.
More text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Place `\unskip` after `\egroup` to make the two invocations behave the same.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{nothing}{\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}
{\egroup\unskip}

\begin{document}
Hello, this is some text.
\begin{nothing}
  This is nothing.
\end{nothing}
More text.

Hello, this is some text.
More text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah - this works for my "minimal example" but apparently it is slightly too minimal... But the other solution below works for me!

Comment: @BartSnapp I agree that egreg's answer is better.  I was the first to upvote it when I saw it appear.