# How can I create an environment which mimics the behavior of a comment-environment?

Tags: macros, sectioning, environments

I intend to configure a document which has at least one translation.
For the moment, the planned languages are English (main) and German.

For a better overview and more compact workflow, I would like to start out with translating the content (and produce the document) with the translated parts in the same `.tex`-file. Imho it is considerably easier to compare the content and subsequently make changes to it. But using `comment`-environments [prevents synctex's "go to source" from working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595885/synctexs-go-to-source-vs-comment-package) which is a truly annoying obstacle which is seemingly unavoidable.

So I found and used [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289718/comment-like-environments-and-spacing).

=> How can I disable the counting mechanism for commands such `\section` and `\label` in the environment(s) which is(are) currently not "active"? I think this environment would then mimic a `comment`-environment.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
parskip=false
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%ENGLISH version (main!) --- - comment out lines below for the German version!!
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newenvironment{len}{\selectlanguage{english}}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\newenvironment{lde}{\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}
{\egroup\ignorespacesafterend}

%%make the German version - comment out lines above for the ENGLISH version!!
%\usepackage[german]{babel}
%\newenvironment{lde}{\selectlanguage{german}}{\ignorespacesafterend}
%\newenvironment{len}{\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}
%{\egroup\ignorespacesafterend}



\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{lde}
\section{Einige Wörter und Füllinhalte}
Abc.
Def.
\end{lde}
\begin{lde}
Mehr Worte.
\end{lde}

\begin{len}
\section{Just some words without meaning}
Abc.
Def.

Again some words to make up a sentence. Aaaa. Bbbbb. Ccccc.

HHHHHHH.
GGGGGG.

\end{len}
\begin{len}
\section{Yes, a truly bad heading}
Page 2: some words to form a sentence.
\end{len}
\begin{lde}
\section{Eine schlechte Überschrift}
Seite 2: Einige deutsche Worte.

Wieder mal ein Satz ohne Sinn. Nimmt quasi kein Ende. Und es geht so weiter, wirklich sinnfrei. Wieder mal ein Satz ohne Sinn. Nimmt quasi kein Ende. Und es geht so weiter, wirklich sinnfrei. Wieder mal ein Satz ohne Sinn. Nimmt quasi kein Ende. Und es geht so weiter, wirklich sinnfrei. 

Und dann noch ein dritter Satz. Äöüi.
\end{lde}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[
parskip=false
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%ENGLISH version (main!) --- - comment out lines below for the German version!!
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{lde}{+b}{}{}

\newenvironment{len}{\selectlanguage{english}}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{lde}
\section{Einige Wörter und Füllinhalte}
Abc.
Def.
\end{lde}
\begin{lde}
Mehr Worte.
\end{lde}

\begin{len}
\section{Just some words without meaning}
Abc.
Def.

Again some words to make up a sentence. Aaaa. Bbbbb. Ccccc.

HHHHHHH.
GGGGGG.

\end{len}
\begin{len}
\section{Yes, a truly bad heading}
Page 2: some words to form a sentence.
\end{len}
\begin{lde}
\section{Eine schlechte Überschrift}
Seite 2: Einige deutsche Worte.

Wieder mal ein Satz ohne Sinn. Nimmt quasi kein Ende. Und es geht so weiter, wirklich sinnfrei. Wieder mal ein Satz ohne Sinn. Nimmt quasi kein Ende. Und es geht so weiter, wirklich sinnfrei. Wieder mal ein Satz ohne Sinn. Nimmt quasi kein Ende. Und es geht so weiter, wirklich sinnfrei.

Und dann noch ein dritter Satz. Äöüi.
\end{lde}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I  want to use the environments for different settings in the preamble. Is it also possible to use the environment for parts in the preamble or should I create a new question for that?

Comment: environments build groups and so are typically not useful for preamble settings. Define some boolean.

Comment: Thank you! `ifthen` seems to be just right for this.